# Batch script if statement returns error 'unexpected at this time'

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch script that writes registry keys for Win7/WinXP so an older video game can run properly, but the batch itself isn't working. The script is as follows:

```
echo on

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080
set VALUE_NAME=InstallLocation
for /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`reg query "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>nul ^| find "%VALUE_NAME%"`) do (

set OUTPUT_SEVEN=%%A%%B
)

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080
set VALUE_NAME=InstallLocation
for /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`reg query "%KEY_NAME%" /v "%VALUE_NAME%" 2^>nul ^| find "%VALUE_NAME%"`) do (
set OUTPUT_XP=%%A%%B
)

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto Win7

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080"
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 goto WinXP


:Win7
(
echo Running Windows 7 Script
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Madia\Echelon" /V Path1 /T reg_sz /D "%OUTPUT_SEVEN%\\Data\\" /F
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Madia\Echelon" /V Path2 /T reg_sz /D "%OUTPUT_SEVEN%\\Data\\" /F
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Echelon" /V InstallLocation /T reg_sz /D "%OUTPUT_SEVEN%\\" /F
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Echelon" /V InstallSource /T reg_sz /D "%OUTPUT_SEVEN%\\" /F
set QQ=%OUTPUT_SEVEN%
goto exit
)

:WinXP
(
echo Running Windows XP Script
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Madia\Echelon" /V Path1 /T reg_sz /D %OUTPUT_XP%\\Data\\" /F
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Madia\Echelon" /V Path2 /T reg_sz /D %OUTPUT_XP%\\Data\\" /F
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Echelon" /V InstallLocation /T reg_sz /D %OUTPUT_XP%\\" /F
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Echelon" /V InstallSource /T reg_sz /D %OUTPUT_XP%\\" /F
set QQ=%OUTPUT_XP%
goto exit
)
:exit
(
start /d"%QQ%" /wait Game.exe
)
```

Running the script in the command prompt:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>gamelauncher.bat

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>echo on

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS


c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE
\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>set VALUE_NAME=InstallLoca
tion

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>for /F "usebackq tokens=3*
" %A IN (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
Uninstall\Steam App 311080" /v "InstallLocation" 2>nul | find "InstallLocation"`
) do (set OUTPUT_SEVEN=%A%B )

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>(set OUTPUT_SEVEN=C:\Progr
amFiles (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Echelon )

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS


c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>set KEY_NAME=HKLM\SOFTWARE
\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>set VALUE_NAME=InstallLoca
tion

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>for /F "usebackq tokens=3*
" %A IN (`reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\St
eam App 311080" /v "InstallLocation" 2>nul | find "InstallLocation"`) do (set OU
TPUT_XP=%A%B )

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\W
ow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 311080"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninsta
ll\Steam App 311080
DisplayIcon REG_SZ C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam\games\1b116bbca7
813266288d61df77b3baca0297aaab.ico
DisplayName REG_SZ Echelon
HelpLink REG_SZ http://support.steampowered.com/
InstallLocation REG_SZ C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\E
chelon
Publisher REG_SZ MADia Entertainment
UninstallString REG_SZ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steam.exe" steam:
//uninstall/311080
URLInfoAbout REG_SZ http://www.madia.ru/echelon.html
NoRepair REG_DWORD 0x1
NoModify REG_DWORD 0x1


c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>if 0 EQU 0 goto Win7
\Steam\steamapps\common\Echelon was unexpected at this time.

c:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Echelon>set QQ=C:\ProgramFiles (x8
6)\Steam\steamapps\common\Echelon
```

If someone smarter than me could figure out what happened here, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem are the parenthesis in the value you are assigning to the variable when

```
set QQ=C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Echelon
```

is executed. Change

```
set QQ=%OUTPUT_SEVEN%
```

into

```
set "QQ=%OUTPUT_SEVEN%"
```

and do the same for the rest of `set` commands. This prevents problems with special characters and avoid the inclusion of unneeded spaces at the end of the stored value.